# Checkout Success Page hanging on load

Tags: php, opencart

New to OpenCart. Just created a site using it. I'm using Sage Pay.

Payments are going through correctly but following the final stage of Sage Pay I get bounced back to:

domain/index.php?route=checkout/success

Which is the correct behaviour but this page doesn't load correctly. The page title appears but I just get a blank screen with no content. After about 30 minutes the page loads.

I can visit the page directly so the page is there and working.

Is there anything I can check to see why its not loading?

Should also say that payments are being processed correctly and the correct emails are going to customers etc.

Comment: Any changes done to success page (controller, template) or to models this is using?

Comment: Not that I know of. I have actually just this minute removed three lines from the htaccess that aren't part of the standard open cart htaccess and it seems to have fixed the problem. I removed #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}? [R=301,L]

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding. I thought I'd found a solution but no I haven't. strange thing is it works in some browsers for example Safari on OS X but not in Chrome on a PC. Can anyone think of anything, client is going crazy.